# Step by step guide for creating cordova android plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I have searched at many places but couldn't find any link describing step by step guide to develop a cordova android plugin.
I have read http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/plugin_ref_spec.md.html#Plugin%20Specification
and understood each component of the plugin.

What I am looking for is a doc which shows steps using an IDE like eclipse and also how to build and publish the plugin.

Comment: Be careful, your link is for 3.0.0 version, phonegap is 3.5 as of today.

Comment: @mentat Thanks for pointing it out. Any links related to using IDE to develop plugins

Answer (score 0):

I cannot point a tutorial online but it's not that different from normal Cordova development. What I suggest is:

- Start a fresh Cordova application
- Try adding the "Echo" plugin as in cordova documentation
- You can use Eclipse to do everything, if you only target Android. You need a Java class and the js side related to the plugin. In total, two files only.
- Look at some existing plugins in github, there are several you can find with http://plugreg.com/
- Implement your own plugin
- Open a repository in github for your plugin, put plugin.xml, java and js files in it.

That's basically all you need to do.

Hope that helps..

Comment: If we check cordova-plugin-file-master they have put in all source files under src\android. The java classes have different packages so IDE like eclipse will complain for that. Do they put these files here after development using some buildscript?

Comment: Plugin.xml do the copying etc.